# i can display an <p> tag with vue js but i cant remove it after 2 sec

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, outerhtml

i have an input field where i can write in something, now if i press enter a value called "gespeichert" gets true. i also have an p tag that is binded with v-if. now i want it to hide / remove it after 2 or 3 seconds.
this is maded with vue.js

i already tried with

```
                    methods: {

        speichern: function() {
            this.gespeichert = true;
            setTimeout(function(){

                    this.gespeichert = false;

            }, 2000);
                             ....
```

now i want that gespeichert gets the value false after 2 seconds, why does this not work?

Comment: use arrow function like `setTimeout(()=>{` in order to access this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope issue - `this` within your setTimeout function is not what it is outside of that function. You can use `.bind(this)` to solve this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    this.gespeichert = false;
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

Comment: perfekt! thank u works exactly how i wanted it :)